# Problems with actionListener of composite component

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

I am goin to explain a problem that I have when I use one composite component inside a template.

Imagine one view like this, that work with a generic managed bean with view scope. I pass it to the template as a parameter.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
  xmlns:trkal="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/trkalcomponents">

  <ui:composition template="/template.xhtml">
      <ui:param name="maisuBean" value="#{genericBean}" />
  </ui:composition>
</html>
```

The template is like this. Beside other components, it also use one composite component.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:trkal="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/trkalcomponents">

<h:head>
    <title>Titulo</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
        ...
        <trkal:toolbarbuttonwidget id="buttonToolbar" label="Action" iconName="toolbar.png"
            buttonAction="#{maisuBean.myActionListener}"
            >
        </trkal:toolbarbuttonwidget>
        ...
        <h:commandLink id="otherButton" actionListener="#{maisuBean.myActionListener}">
            <h:graphicImage library="images" name="toolbar.png" />
            <h:outputText value="Other Action" />
        </h:commandLink>
        ...

    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

As you can see, this template use one composite components that allow specify the action listener that hear this event.

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="id" />
    <composite:attribute name="buttonAction" method-signature="void myAction(javax.faces.event.ActionEvent)" targetAttributeName="actionListener"/>
    <composite:attribute name="iconName" />
    <composite:attribute name="label"/>
    <composite:attribute name="title"/>
    <composite:attribute name="styleClass"/>
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>
    <h:outputStylesheet target="head" library="trkalcomponents" name="toolbarbuttonwidget.css"  />
    <h:commandLink id="buttonAction">
        <h:graphicImage library="images" name="#{cc.attrs.iconName}" />
        <h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.label}" />
    </h:commandLink>
</composite:implementation>
```

If I click in **otherButton**, it work fine, but if I click in **buttonToolbar** it don't work.

```
09-nov-2012 19:16:28 javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener processAction
GRAVE: Se ha recibido 'javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException' al invocar la escucha de acción '#{maisuBean.myActionListener}' para el componente 'buttonAction'
09-nov-2012 19:16:28 javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener processAction
GRAVE: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /template.xhtml @20,6 buttonAction="#{maisuBean.myActionListener}": Propiedad 'myActionListener' no hallada en el tipo com.joxeja.test.ToolBarBean
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:111)
```

It seem that it can't resolve the EL expression inside the composite component.

What is wrong? How can I use one composite componente inside one template?

I am using Mojarra 2.1.7

Thanks.

Comment: #{maisuBean.myActionListener}' <--I think this is giving you a pretty big hint. What's the code for your ActionListner? And is the bean registered?

Comment: Yes, the bean is registered and as I say it works if I click in otherButton commandLink. The bean is registered as **@ManagedBean(name="genericBean") and @ViewScoped.**

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I missed this on the first read:

Your implementation isn't targeting the attributes properly. I made this mistake (as I'm pretty sure all of us do). You need to reference the attributes as -> `#{cc.attrs.someAttribute}` not by their name. You do this for most of the elements, but not the `actionListener`. If that is your code it should fix it. Your signatures are correct. You're trying to use the `targetAttributeName` which I'm not familiar with. My guess is you need to set the `id` of the component to that name (so your button would be `myAction` not `actionListener` (if I'm referencing the same example you are).

That aside, how I would do it is:

```
    <composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="id" />
    <!-- 
    <composite:attribute name="buttonAction" method-signature="void myAction(javax.faces.event.ActionEvent)" targetAttributeName="actionListener"/>
    -->
    <composite:attribute name="buttonAction" method-signature="void action(javax.faces.event.ActionEvent)"/>  
    <composite:attribute name="iconName" />
    <composite:attribute name="label"/>
    <composite:attribute name="title"/>
    <composite:attribute name="styleClass"/>
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>
    <h:outputStylesheet target="head" library="trkalcomponents" name="toolbarbuttonwidget.css"  />
        <!-- fix below -->
        <h:commandLink id="buttonAction" actionListener=#{cc.attrs.buttonAction}>
            <h:graphicImage library="images" name="#{cc.attrs.iconName}" />
            <h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.label}" />
        </h:commandLink>
    </composite:implementation>
```

I like this method because it is similar to the rest of the way pages are marked up and it seems simple. Give it a shot.

Comment: Many thanks for the help, but I had tried this way and the result is the same. The error message is that it can't found the property **myActionListener** of the managed bean **genericBean**. It like as it try call to getter method for this property, and logically it doesn't exist.

Comment: To confirm: if you do -> `<h:commandButton actionListener="#{genericBean.myActionListener}" />` in the form it works? Your error sounds like it doesn't work at all, not that it doesn't work inside the component.

Comment: Yes, the commandLink **otherButton** of the template works fine, but the toolbarbuttonwidget **buttonToolbar** of the teamplate don't work. One big detail. I can't put **genericBean**.myActionListener because the template manage the bean **maisuBean**. The template receive the reference of the bean as a parameter. There are some level: use page, template and composite componente, every one manage its bean, that receive or pass as parameter. In each level I can use  its reference. The problem given in the composite componente that can't resolve the EL expression for the listener method.