# ui:param can't be evaluated in actionListener inside a composite component

Tags: jsf

If I pass an expression to a composite component like

`<My:myButton action="#{bean.myaction()" value="#{bean.buttText()}"`

and try to use it in

```
<cc:implementation>
 <h:commandButton actionListener="#{cc.attrs.action} value="#{cc.attrs.value}...
```

I get the exception "**Target Unreachable, identifier 'bean' resolved to null**".

**But only** if bean is a `<ui:param name="bean" value="#{myRealBean}"/>` inside a template. The error only occours with actionListener. The button text, resolved from the same bean in the same way will be shown.

This old [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313885/problems-with-actionlistener-of-composite-component) seems to have the same problem but no answer.

If I split the parameter to

`<My:myButton bean="#{bean}" method="myaction" value="#{bean.buttText()}"`

and use

```
<cc:implementation>
<h:commandButton actionListener="#{cc.attrs.bean[cc.attrs.method]()} ...
```

no error occours and everything works fine.

How can I use a function-expression in an actionListener inside a composite component, where the bean is a `<ui:param`?

```
Glassfish 4.1.1, Mojarra 2.2.12
```

And now, the MCVE

a bean:

```
package beans;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class Testbean implements Serializable {
    public String getButtText() { return "Submit"; }
    public void doAction() { System.out.println("Ajax was here."); }
}
```

a page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets" xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
         xmlns:ST="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/softeam" >
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="testform">
        <h:panelGrid columns="1">
            <ui:include src="testtemplate.xhtml">
                <ui:param name="bean" value="#{testbean}"/>
            </ui:include>
            <ST:testButt text="#{testbean.buttText}" action="#{testbean.doAction()}"/>
            <h:commandButton value="#{testbean.buttText}" actionListener="#{testbean.doAction()}"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

and a template

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:ST="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/softeam">

        <ST:testButt text="#{bean.buttText}" action="#{bean.doAction()}"/>
        <h:commandButton value="#{bean.buttText}" action="#{bean.doAction()}" />
</ui:composition>
```

and the component

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:S="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite" >
    <S:interface>
        <S:attribute name="action" method-signature="void action()"/>
        <S:attribute name="text"   type="java.lang.String"/>
    </S:interface>

    <S:implementation>
        <h:commandButton style="display:inline-block"
                         value="#{cc.attrs.text}"
                         actionListener="#{cc.attrs.action}"
        />
    </S:implementation>
</html>
```

All buttons will be shown (with the bean.buttText()) but only the second, third and fourth will call the action. The first button throws an exception when clicked.

**Edit:** Example reduced to JSF, no PrimeFaces components.

Comment: The other question is not identical imo since it is about a property not found exception. But it might be related if you are using the same old Mojarra 2.1.7. Tried a newer version? Oh and please make an [mcve] to so others can see  you don't have any other mistakes.

Comment: Great [mcve] Some questions still: Does it fail too when not using ajax on the buttons or the partial submits? Does it also fail with a plain `h:commandButton`? Can you try adding a `type="java.lang.Object"` to the `<S:attribute name="action"` and if I understand correctly, using `<ST:testButt action="#{bean.doAction()}"...` in the page directly does work too? and can you see if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29017273/pass-method-expression-attribute-through-to-nested-composite-component helps?

Comment: I've changed all buttons to `<h:commandButton`, stripped all other `<p:` tokens and added a 4th button `<ST:testButt action="#{testbean.doAction()}" text="#{testbean.buttText}"/>` in the main page. All but the first button are ok. With `type="java.lang.Object"` the page doesn't appear. NullPointerException in `com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy$MethodRetargetHandlerManager$ArbitraryMethodRegargetHandler.retarget`

Comment: Can you please add/change the `h:`/`p:` things and the additional button in the Q too? So if I try to reproduce I know I have the same source.  And sure the NPE is caused by the `type="java.lang.Object"`? Not by adding a `targets` or did you add both?

Comment: No, I only replaced `method-signature` with `type`. I've edited the question.

Comment: I'll try tonight if I can reproduce on wildfly 13